# Handling zero timout deployments with Nginx

Tags: nginx

Is there a way to configure Nginx to accept requests, but not pass them on to the backend for a period of time?

If we could create a 5-second window (arbitrary number) during which no requests were dropped, then we could complete our DB migrations on the backend before continuing to accept requests. Thus implementing a zero-downtime deployment. I assume there would be restrictions on memory requirements.

The end result to the user is that for a few seconds the request-response cycle would be slow, but wouldn't drop entirely, and would not result in errors.

Comment: Is it possible to increase timeout on nginx?